# What books did Elend read that we know of?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn, the-final-empire

I'm asking titles and conveniently the themes of each book. Does anyone know if there exists a list somewhere that someone might have created? Asking for a friend

Comment: If you can figure out how to run search queries at coppermind.net, that's probably the best source. Example: https://coppermind.net/wiki/Dilisteni

Answer (score 8):

here is a swift list of books & authors discussed by Elend during the three books (along with chapter numbers for each):

- Trials of Monument - Dilisteni (Mistborn #12)
- City Management in the Modern Era - Jendellah (Mistborn #13)
- ?? - Heberen (Mistborn #18)
- Book of the False Dawn - Deluse Couvre (Mistborn #18 #19)
- ?? - Redalevin (Mistborn #23)
- ?? - Temadre (Mistborn #36)
- Studies in Revolution - Ytves (Well of Ascension #32)
- Calling of Trust - Durton (Hero of Ages #32)
- ?? - Gallingskaw (Hero of Ages #32)
- ?? - Hardren (Hero of Ages #32)
- ?? - Urdree (Hero of Ages #32)
- ?? - Trendalan (Hero of Ages #44)
- Supplying in Scale - Trentison (Hero of Ages #70)

As [@Amarth pointed out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221363/what-books-did-elend-read-that-we-know-of#comment604739_221373) Alendi's journal (the epigraphs throughout the first book) are also read by Elend.

Comment: Also, if it counts as a book, Alendi's journal.

Comment: Was there some trick to finding this on Coppermind, or was this just manual digging?  Also, totally tangential question for my own curiosity, as host of the Coppermind, did you have anything to do with making the Arcanum, or was that something separate that was kinda melded into the coppermind domain?

Comment: I found this list by visiting each of the [Category: Scholars](https://coppermind.net/wiki/Category:Scholars) articles and noting down each of those who were a part of the Final Empire (or otherwise referencing Elend).

Comment: I personally haven't been involved in the content collection part of Arcanum, but I was involved in the coding of some of the precursors and provided inspiration and encouragement to the creator of the [Palanaeum](https://github.com/Palanaeum/palanaeum) system and specifically (at least claim to be) asked for the transcription audio snippeting side of things.

many of the other Coppermind staff have been heavily involved in organisation and transcription for Arcanum and some of the other Arcanists have since become good wiki people :3

Comment: @fbstj That's pretty awesome.  The Cradle series is also making use of the Palanaeum system.  It's a really handy tool for series where the authors interact so much with the fans.